# jstat and JSP configuration

Tags: java, jsp, jstat

I have installed and configured [jstat](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jstat.html) in my PC with Windows XP, tested it with sample Java program. But I need to know how to use jstat with JSP or Tomcat, is there any other futher configuration needed or not?

Comment: Note that Java/JSP should really not to be confused with JavaScript (which you tagged first). JavaScript is an entirely different language with different purposes.

Comment: ok BalusC by mistake i wrote javascript for java

Answer (score 0):

In principle not. You can just write, import and execute Java code in a JSP or preferably in a Servlet class the same way as you do with a "plain vanilla" Java class. The webserver has however to run at the same machine as the jstat runs.